# Weird Entity Manager Error

Tags: java, openjpa

I've made this query:

```
Usuario user1=(Usuario) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
String query1 = "SELECT f FROM Favorito f WHERE f.usuarioBean = 'user1'";
```

I call the Manager method here

```
List<Favorito> favoritos = managerFavorito.getFavoritoByUser(query1);
```

And the Manager method looks like this:

```
public List<Favorito> getFavoritoByUser(String query1) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        List<Favorito> results = null;
        try {
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(query1);
            results = (List<Favorito>) query.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return results;
    }
```

The error:

```
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Metadata not found for type "class java.lang.String". Class not improved.
```

Full error :

```
[25/11/12 0:17:37:538 CET] 0000002b servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Se ha creado una excepción no detectada en uno de los métodos de servicio del servlet servletControl en la aplicación MotorSalesGR83.15. Excepción creada: <openjpa-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1032678 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: No se han encontrado metadatos para el tipo "class java.lang.String". La clase no se ha mejorado.
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:377)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:358)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.getMapping(MappingRepository.java:355)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.RelationStrategies.toDataStoreValue(RelationStrategies.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.RelationFieldStrategy.toDataStoreValue(RelationFieldStrategy.java:836)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.toDataStoreValue(FieldMapping.java:938)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.PCPath.toDataStoreValue(PCPath.java:844)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.Lit.calculateValue(Lit.java:109)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.CompareEqualExpression.appendTo(CompareEqualExpression.java:98)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.SelectConstructor.buildWhere(SelectConstructor.java:298)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.SelectConstructor.evaluate(SelectConstructor.java:93)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreQuery.createWhereSelects(JDBCStoreQuery.java:349)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreQuery.executeQuery(JDBCStoreQuery.java:187)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery$DataStoreExecutor.executeQuery(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:776)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1003)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:861)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:792)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:288)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at entities.controller.FavoritoManager.getVehiculoFavorito(FavoritoManager.java:172)
    at tiw.servletControl.doPost(servletControl.java:78)
    at tiw.servletControl.doGet(servletControl.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3933)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Something wrong? I'm starting to think I cannot search for row in Favorito using a simple Where.

Comment: Please post full stacktrace and show us where you got that exception

Comment: The stack trace says that the exception is thrown by `entities.controller.FavoritoManager.getVehiculoFavorito(FavoritoManager.java:172)`, and not by the method above.

Answer (score 1):

There are some odd things going on in your code.

Firstly, you are pulling the `user1` object out of the session, but never using it. Furthermore, in your query, you are asserting that `f.usuarioBean` is equal to the string 'user1', which i would imagine can never be true:

```
String query1 = "SELECT f FROM Favorito f WHERE f.usuarioBean = 'user1'";
```

I think you mean to do something like this:

```
String query1 = "SELECT f FROM Favorito f WHERE f.usuarioBean = '" + user1.getId() + "'";
```

An even better way to do this (really, the only right way to do this), would be to use a query parameter:

```
String query1 = "SELECT f FROM Favorito f WHERE f.usuarioBean = ?";
// and then later:
query.setParameter(1, user1);
```

Secondly, you're calling [`createNativeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29), which takes an SQL query string as a parameter. However, the string you're passing isn't SQL, it's JPQL (you couldn't select a table alias in SQL, could you?). You should be calling [`createQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29), or better yet, the overload [`createQuery(String, Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29), which creates a `TypedQuery`, for better type-safety.